# Настройка .htaccess для ошибки 404 на двух языках

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Есть сайт на веб-сервере apache. Необходимо настроить .htaccess так, чтобы при переходе по адресу вида example.com/несуществующая_страница - отображалась страница 404.html, а при переходе по адресу вида example.com/ru/несуществующая_страница отображалась страница ru/404.html.

Один в один проблема решается тут:
https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/404-pages-on-localhost-for-multilingual-site-failing/40568/2
Только для локального сервера Hugo:

```
[[redirects]]
from = '/ru/**'
to = '/ru/404.html'
status = 404

[[redirects]]  # Default lang, should be last.
from = '/**'
to = '/404.html'
status = 404
```

Текущая версия моего .htaccess такая:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ru/(.*)$ /ru/404.html [L]
```

Перекидывает и с `example.com/ru/test` и с `example.com/test` на английскую версию 404.html, т.е. на ту, которая лежит в корне сайта.

Comment: так правила поменяйте местами ваши. Очевидно же всегда будет отрабатывать первое

Comment: @teran, мне не очевидно, было бы очевидно - не задавал бы тут вопросы.

Comment: вам могло это быть не очевидно ранее, но теперь вы, надеюсь, поняли суть, и это стало очевидным? Вообще для подобной конфигурации `ErrorDocument` можно, наверное, настроить в корневой папке и в `ru` дополнительным htaccess.

Comment: @teran, угу, спасибо. Теперь действительно очевидно.